# Firebase admin CDN not found

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, firebase-admin

I'm working on this app that needs to be as simple as possible plain vanillaJS, not npm packages if possible. I have been working with firebase and the way I have been working with it is by using the cnds as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

All good until here..but when I tried to use the admin cdn and got a **404** errors since it wasn't found.

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-admin.js"></script>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

I didn't find the cdn on the docs, is it different? does it even exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not supported.  The Firebase Admin SDK is **not** meant for use in web browsers.  It's for backend/desktop code running nodejs.

You can see the instructions to get started with Firebase Admin [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).  You're expected to be using nodejs and npm to install the libraries.

Comment: cool! makes sense Doug. Is there another way to subscribe to topics other than doing this...https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/103#issuecomment-279355632 then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to use the firebase admin, so i can subscribe to a topic on FCM as shown here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics#subscribe-and-unsubscribe-using-the-adminSDK, but since firebase admin is not meant to use on web, I have to use the post request as shown on the github link https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/103#issuecomment-279355632. So i was wondering if theres a cleaner way to do it

Comment: FCM clients have their own way of subscribing to a topic.  Is there anything wrong with that API?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: There's is not wrong with it, i was wandering if there was a better way or cleaner way to do so! Thanks for you help Doug!